# Google sheet search for latest cell value within condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to force my google sheet to find latest value of cell within 2 conditions. I'll explain in example for better understanding as I am not able to put this in words properly.

I have a sheet with two tables:
In Table A is reminders with dates for each address.
In Table B is a list of names with address.

I need to add last reminder number to the table B taken from table A for each address.
So I need the sheet to look through table A addresses, and where the address matches with the table B row pick the latest reminder based on date in the sheet.

**Example:**

```
Table A
Name    Address Number  Date
John    Blueberry hill 45   1   01/05/2023
John    Blueberry hill 45   2   02/05/2023
Tom     Strawberry road 3   1   03/05/2023
Elsa    Morning avenue 67   1   02/05/2023
Anna    Evening street 23   1   05/05/2023
Anna    Evening street 23   2   07/05/2023
John    Blueberry hill 45   3   07/05/2023
Anna    Evening street 23   3   11/05/2023
Elsa    Morning avenue 67   2   17/05/2023
Tom     Strawberry road 3   2   19/05/2023
Anna    Evening street 23   1   23/05/2023
        
Table B
Name    Address Latest reminder
John    Blueberry hill 45   3
Tom     Strawberry road 3   2
Elsa    Morning avenue 67   2
Anna    Evening street 23   1
```

John had 3 reminders (last one was 7th May)

Tom had 2 reminders (last one was 7th May)

Elsa had 2 reminders (last one was 17th May)

Anna had 1 reminder (last 23rd May even though on 11th May she had 3, we need that 1 as it is last by date)

I tried query but I cannot make it first check for same address and THEN look for latest date. Anyone able to help me please?

Adding the testing sheet if anyone wants to play with it:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bjoteUJpm96z3zpIejowtuhO88MlpuWgGVkhuz63Kac/edit#gid=0

I tried google query but it only took both condition at once (latest date AND same address) which doesn't work as I need.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=index(ifna(vlookup(G2:G&H2:H,sort({A:A&B:B,C:C,D:D},3,),2,)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(G2:G&H2:H,A:A&B:B,C:C,,,-1))
```